# $f(A,B) = trace(A^tMB)$, prove that if f is symmetric then M is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, bilinear-form

> Let $V$ be the space of $2\times2$ matrices  over $\mathbb R$, let $M
> \in V$, and let $f:V \times V\to \mathbb R$ a bilinear form such that
>   $f(A,B) = trace(A^tMB)$ for all $A,B \in V$. Prove that f symmetric if
>   and only if M is symmetric.

The first "if" is easy:

Assuming $M=M^t$, then $f(A,B)=trace(A^tMB)=trace[(A^tMB)^t]=trace[(MB)^tA]=trace(B^tM^tA)=trace(B^tMA)=f(B,A)$

But I couldn't prove the other direction, any hints?

Comment: Maybe try looking at the bilinear form on the standard basis: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Does "$f$ is symmetric" mean $f(A,B)=f(B,A)$ for all $A, B$" ?

Comment: @kimchilover yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove the result is as follows. Note that $$f(A,B)=f(B,A) \implies \operatorname{trace}(A^t MB)-\operatorname{trace}(B^t MA)=0.$$
But $$\operatorname{trace}(B^t MA) = \operatorname{trace}((B^t MA)^t)=\operatorname{trace}(A^t M^t B).$$
Therefore,
$$f(A,B)=f(B,A) \implies \operatorname{trace}(A^t MB)-\operatorname{trace}(A^t M^t B)=\operatorname{trace}(A^t (M-M^t)B)=0.$$
Put $B = I$ and $A = M-M^t$ to arrive at
$$\operatorname{trace}((M-M^t)^t (M-M^t))=\|M-M^t\|_F^2 = 0 \implies M = M^t.$$

Note that, for any real matrix $X$, $\operatorname{trace}(X^t X)$ is the sum of the squares of its elements.

Comment: Doesn't this show that it's true only if $B=I, A=M-M^t$?

Comment: The result is true for all $A$ and $B$. I took some particular matrices to prove the result. Note that $f(A,B) = f(B,A)$ for **all** $A, B \in V$. So the result should also be true for $B=I$ and $A = M-M^t$.

Comment: Right.. Nice prove thanks

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to try with $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Since $f$ is symmetric:
$$
0 = f(A,I)-f(I,A) =trace(A^\top\,M)-trace(M\,A) =M_{12} -M_{21}
$$
Thus $M_{12} =M_{21}$.